# Visual Studio keeps deleting code in form.designers

Tags: c#, events, windows-forms-designer, auto-generate, form-designer

I'm making a winform application. I'm trying to add a keydown event to a combo box so I prepared the event implementation and then I added inside the form.designers document the line:

```
this.cmboxSearchPath.KeyDown += cmboxSearchPath_KeyDown;
```

for some reason this line always get deleted from the document.. do you know why and how can I stop it from being deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for some reason this line always get deleted from the document.. do you know why and how can I stop it from being deleted?

Don't put it in the designer generated code.  You can include this in your constructor after the `InitializeComponent()` call, or allow the designer to generate this for you by wiring up the event via the designer itself.

Comment: The designer just seems like the perfect place for everything.. I believe it should be there and not in the constructoe... What do you mean about "allow the designer to generate this for you by wiring up the event via the designer itself" ?

Comment: @YonatanNir If you click on the combo box in the designer (not the .cs file, but the visual designer), and go to the properties window, then choose "events" at the top, and double click on "KeyDown".  The designer will take care of adding this for you.

Comment: one of the dumbest thing I have to deal with working in winform. If you create event from the designer it puts the code in the designer.cs. But if you manually add the event in there somehow it doesn't like it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to modify the `desginer.cs` file. Attach the event in the form designer or you can attach the event in the code behind *(form.cs)*. It is probably disappearing if you are loading the form in the designer and you are getting the message to ignore changes and reload design.